# Using .net 4.0 Vs .net 4.5

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have an existing winform application developed in .net 4.0. Now, we don't want to support Win Xp as Microsoft is also going to stop the support for Xp this year. We are going to support win 7 onward from now on. So, now we are open to explore the benefits of .net 4.5 or .net 4.5.1.

My application is a sort of media player. So, our main dilemma is whether upgrading to newer version of .net will help us or would not make any difference.
Please share your views on whether to switch to higher .net version or not.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx It is not a good question for SO, as it is too subjective.

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit i see you will get by the upgrade is a better `GC`.

1. Background Server GC (this will not help you, primarily for ASP.NET,WCF based applications)
2. Collecting Large object heaps, if your desktop application works with large datasets this will help

Detailed below.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx

Finally,

1. Considering desktop application, `I don't think upgrade is worth if a deployment is planned solely for .Net 4.5 Upgrade` unless collecting LOH helps you. If you have a upcoming release planned add this as a action item.
2. Go for the upgrade if the GC upgrade helps you in LOH and also it's better to `plan a proper perf test to check the benefits` before moving to prod.